# Can I determine if an argument is string literal?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to determine if an argument passed in macro or function is a string literal at compile time or run time?

For example,

```
#define is_string_literal(X)
...
...   

is_string_literal("hello") == true;
const char * p = "hello";
is_string_literal(p) == false;
```

or

```
bool is_string_literal(const char * s);

is_string_literal("hello") == true;
const char * p = "hello";
is_string_literal(p) == false;
```

Thanks.

Comment: For a purpose, or just wondering?

Comment: What if I initialized a named pointer to a string literal like `const char* p = "hello";` somewhere else, then passed the value of that pointer `p` to `is_string_literal()`? Should it return `true` or `false`?

Comment: It would be nice to return true in this case. But to reduce the difficulty, it can return false. I am more interested in detecting a string literal, not a pointer to a string literal

Comment: @absurd: Well then, why do you need a `is_string_literal()` function? If the intent of `is_string_literal()` is to test if a string is not modifiable, then the function as you describe will give many false negatives, greatly reducing its usefulness.

Comment: Not really. Strictly speaking, p is not a string literal if const char * p = "Hello". So returning false is appropriate.

Comment: @absurd: Again, what is this for?

Comment: @absurd: Okay, how about this: Is there a use-case you can present for `is_string_literal()`? Under what situations do you think something like a `is_string_literal()` would help? I ask because I really can't see how it can be useful.

Comment: For example, if we know p is a string literal, we could safely hand it to another thread and don't need to worry about the ownership problem since a string literal is immutable and always in memory.

Comment: @absurd: Well your non-literal strings should be `std::string`'s, so just toss the literal cases into one and send it over.

Comment: @absurd: You can solve the ownership problem more elegantly and consistently by using locks, or even simpler, giving each thread their own copy of the string (via `std::string`s as GMan has suggested).

Comment: That will not be as efficient as just passing a pointer p, right ?

Comment: @absurd: Efficiency isn't as important as getting things working in a clear and succinct fashion. `std::string` does that. (Yes, it's unfortunately literals aren't as improved as they could be, but it's not something to worry about until it's a measurable problem.)

Comment: @absurd, you can do it efficiently without any calculations using templates. Look at my answer.

Comment: I still can't seem to see the use-case of such a macro/function. When you use it in code like `is_literal("oh hi")`, you already know it is a literal. When you use it on, say, a parameter, you can't distinguish from literal or non-literal, because the literal gets bound to the `char const*`.

Comment: @Xeo - It could be used in macro expansion: `#define func(s) realfunc(s, is_literal(s) ? sizeof(s) - 1 : strlen(s))` The macro wraps around the function, allowing other (possibly hidden) parameters to be adjusted if the string is a literal. The above example is contrived, as the `sizeof` technique works equally well for (non-literal) arrays and could easily be rewritten to do so, but it's possible that a semi-reasonable use-case can be constructed.

Comment: @Chris: Okay, that example convinced me. :)

Comment: @Chris: That example is a hideous case of premature optimization resulting in obfuscation. Any decent compiler will optimize out `strlen("literal")` at compile-time, or you could just write `sizeof` yourself and make it clean what's going on rather than hiding it behind macros that will confuse the reader of the code.

Comment: @GMan Sometimes efficiency is more important than style. The end user does not care about how the source code is written. And sometimes, they want the best performance more than anything else.

Comment: @absurd: I didn't say anything about style, that's a misrepresentation. Correctness *is* more important than efficiency. If it weren't, I've just written every program ever as efficiently as possible: `int main(){}`. What good is a fast program if it's broken? Just write it in a clean fashion first.

Comment: @absurd, if knowing at compile time (as you mentioned in your question) is ok then you can see my edited answer. That's very simple. It throws compiler error if it's not a string literal.

Comment: Another example use case is Qt with translations. The `QObject::tr()` function only accepts string literals (with some rare exceptions for `QT_TR_NOOP` and such) because it uses a separate utility to locate all `tr()` calls and extract the literals to translation source XML files to be handed to translators and then reincorporated as data files in the project. If you don't put only string literals in, translation won't work properly. This technique may be of some help there.

Answer (score 27):

YES! (Thanks to [James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151292/james-mcnellis) and [GMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gman) for corrections. Updated to correctly handle concatenated literals like `"Hello, " "World!"` which get stringized before concatenation.)

```
#define is_literal_(x) is_literal_f(#x, sizeof(#x) - 1)
#define is_literal(x) is_literal_(x)

bool is_literal_f(const char *s, size_t l)
{
    const char *e = s + l;
    if(s[0] == 'L') s++;
    if(s[0] != '"') return false;
    for(; s != e; s = strchr(s + 1, '"'))
      {
        if(s == NULL) return false;
        s++;
        while(isspace(*s)) s++;
        if(*s != '"') return false;
      }
    return true;
}
```

This will stringify the argument before passing it to the function, so if the argument was a string literal, the argument passed to our function will be surrounded with quote characters.

If you consider this a string literal:

```
const char *p = "string";
// should is_literal(p) be true or false?
```

I cannot help you. You might be able to use some implementation-defined (or *shudder* undefined) behavior to test whether or not a string is stored in read-only memory, but on some (probably older) systems `p` could be modified.

For those who question the use of such a function, consider:

```
enum string_type { LITERAL, ARRAY, POINTER };

void string_func(/*const? */char *c, enum string_type t);
```

Rather than explicitly specifying the second argument to `string_function` on every call, `is_literal` allows us to wrap it with a macro:

```
#define string_func(s) \
    (string_func)(s, is_literal(s)  ? LITERAL :
        (void *)s == (void *)&s ? ARRAY : POINTER)
```

I can't imagine why it would make a difference, except in plain C where literals aren't `const` and for some reason you don't want to/can't write the function as taking a `const char *` instead of a `char`. But there are all kinds of reasons to want to do something. Someday you, too may feel the need to resort to a horrible hack.

Comment: `func(L":P :)")`. (To be fair, you can add an overload.)

Comment: `func__` needs to take a `const char*`, no?  It still doesn't work, though, because if I declare `const char x[] = "Hello, World!";` and call `func(x)`, I just get `s` as a pointer to `"x"`.

Comment: Even if it works, I would immediately reject it in a code review. It's such a massive WTF.

Comment: @James - Good catch, I was experimenting with different `main` signatures today and got mixed up. I was unclear whether the OP wanted `const char *p = "test"` to return true or false, but `const char a[] = "test"` is not (IMHO) a string literal, as the string literal is copied into an array that can be modified.

Comment: @In silico - Any code that relies on knowing whether a function is passed a string literal or a more mutable string is probably already going to fail a code review.

Comment: Ok; I'll buy that:  it does test _whether_ the argument is a string literal; you just can't do anything useful with the function.  [Edit: actually, you need to walk the whole string in the function to handle e.g. `is_literal("Hello, " omghax "World!")`.]

Comment: @James - You could use it to test whether you can use `sizeof str - 1` instead of `strlen(str)` (but a simple `sizeof(str) == sizeof(char *)` would suffice for that - it'd fail for strings of length 3, but that's not a significant optimization concern).

Comment: @GMan - I didn't realize this question was tagged C++. I wonder if there's a way to do it in pure C...

Comment: @GMan - Actually, no overload needed. `L":P :)"` will stringize to `"L\":P :)\""`, which is still a `char *` rather than a `wchar_t *`. Instead of an overload, you just need to do `s[0] == '"' || (s[0] == 'L' && s[1] == '"')`

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Nice solution. Thanks!  Is it possible to get a compile time solution ?

Comment: Just as a side remark, I think double underscore is not allowed for C++ identifiers, I think.

Comment: I think we can do it more elegantly using templates. Look at my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nice solution and trick, but like @James says, you can't do anything useful - see my comment on the question and please correct me if it actually can be used for something. :)

Comment: @Jens - My Google-fu failed me. Fixing. @iammilind - No, `char x[] = "test"` is not a string literal, it is an array (which is mutable). `char *x = "test"` is arguably a string literal (and undoubtedly points to one). `"test"` is a string literal, and cannot be distinguished from `char x[] = "test"` with templates. @Xeo - The OP didn't ask for a use for this trick, just the trick itself. If you think the question is bad, don't downvote the answer.

Comment: While this answer is correct, it's also impractical, because it needs to be passed the literal, erm, _literally_. At every place in code where you could use this macro you can see the literal anyway. Once you handed it down as an argument to a function, this won't work anymore.

Comment: @sbi - Not true. It can be used to detect literals passed as arguments to a macro.

Comment: @Chris, edited answer for knowing string literal at compile time by throwing error for non-literals.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: This is a nice answer, but the `ARRAY` check is unreliable for `char s[sizeof(char *)]`. Also, one practical use of knowing if the argument is a literal or not is the ability to know you can use a specialized associative array lookup based on the literal pointer value, instead of computing a hash.

Comment: @user315052 - I figured that, for strings that are only `sizeof(char *)` long, any efficiency gain/loss provided by knowing if it's an array or a pointer will be insignificant, and it will probably be unnecessary to distinguish between the two. If I found an actual use case for it, I would come up with a more bullet-proof solution.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Just thought of an array check. For an array, the address of the array equals the array.

Comment: You can totally do something useful with it, this is ideal for a logger that wants to avoid copying strings uselessly. Loggers often use macro has entry points anyway. It just requires making the detection code constexpr to be passed to a template downstream. Obviously, I'd rather see proper support, but in the mean time, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 6):

Knowing at compile time (as mentioned in question), with following technique. You can determine if the a given argument is string literal or not. If it's some array or pointer like `const char x[], *p`; then it will throw compiler error.

```
#define is_string_literal(X) _is_string_literal("" X)
bool _is_string_literal (const char *str) { return true; } // practically not needed
```

[Note: My previous answer was down voted by experts and it's yet not accepted or up voted after edits. I am putting an another answer with same content.]

Comment: Your approach does not seem to fit the OP's goal. It could be used to assert that `X` is a string literal, but there would still be many false positives: for example `is_string_literal(+0)` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes; in C++20:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#define IS_SL(x) ([&]<class T = char>() { \
    return std::is_same_v<decltype(x), T const (&)[sizeof(x)]> and \
    requires { std::type_identity_t<T[sizeof(x) + 1]>{x}; }; }())
```

That is, a string literal is something with type reference to const array of char that can be used to initialize an array of char of the same size or greater. (The last point is to guard against the possible adoption of [P1997](https://wg21.link/p1997) **Relaxing Restrictions on Arrays**, which would allow initializing a `char[6]` from a `char const[6]`, but not from a `char const[5]`.)

Test cases:

```cpp
#include <source_location>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    static_assert(IS_SL("hello"));
    static_assert(IS_SL("hello" "world"));
    static_assert(IS_SL(R"(hello)"));
    static_assert(not IS_SL(0));
    static_assert(not IS_SL(argc));
    static_assert(not IS_SL(argv[0]));
    char const s[] = "hello";
    static_assert(not IS_SL(s));
    constexpr char const cs[] = "hello";
    static_assert(not IS_SL(cs));
    constexpr char const* sp = "hello";
    static_assert(not IS_SL(sp));
    static_assert(IS_SL(__FILE__));
    static_assert(not IS_SL(std::source_location::current().file_name()));
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/TMG5r9ffz

Comment: Won't work for `wchar_t` and other non-one-byte types

Comment: @Kaiyakha yes, it should be obvious how to extend it to wide string literals.

Answer (score 4):

No.  A string literal is just an array of `char` (in C) or `const char` (in C++).

You can't distinguish between a string literal and some other array of `char` like this one (in C++):

```
const char x[] = "Hello, World!";
```

Comment: But could you use a `sizeof(s) != sizeof(void *)` hack to differentiate string literals (or arrays) from a `char*`. You'd get tripped up by `s = "sss"` on 32bit systems of course. I'm not recommending such a thing of course.

Comment: @mu is too short:  `sizeof("Hello, World!")` is 14.  `sizeof(x)` (given the `x` in my example) is 14.  A string literal is an array like any other.

Comment: Yes, I know a string literal is just an array with an automatic null terminator, hence the `char*` reference in my comment.

Comment: @James, look at my answer. We can very well do it.

Comment: @iammilind: I find it interesting that you downvoted this answer but your so-called elegant "solution" doesn't even work for the trivial case I present here in my answer.

Comment: @James, edited answer for knowing for string literal at compile time by throwing error for non-literals.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple portable approach for both C and C++, completely evaluated at compile time, that tests for simple narrow string literals, ie: single string literals without backslashes:

```
#define STR(s)  #s
#define is_string_literal(s)  (sizeof(STR(#s)) == sizeof(#s) + 4 \
                               && #s[0] == '"' && #s[sizeof(#s)-2] == '"')
```

It simply tests that the string conversion starts and ends with a `"` and that applying the string conversion twice only increases the length of the string by 4, only escaping the initial and trailing `"`.

Here is a test program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR(s)  #s
#define is_simple_string(s)  (sizeof(STR(#s)) == sizeof(#s) + 4 \
                              && #s[0] == '"' && #s[sizeof(#s)-2] == '"')

int main() {
#define TEST(s)  printf("%16s -> %d\n", #s, is_simple_string(s))
    char buf[4] = "abc";
    const char cbuf[4] = "def";
    char *p = buf;
    const char *cp = cbuf;

#define S "abc"
    TEST(1);
    TEST('x');
    TEST(1.0);
    TEST(1LL);
    TEST(main);
    TEST(main());
    TEST(S);
    TEST("");
    TEST("abc");
    TEST("abc\n");
    TEST("abc\"def");
    TEST("abc" "");
    TEST("abc"[0]);
    TEST("abc"+1);
    TEST("abc"-*"def");
    TEST(""+*"");
    TEST("a"+*"");
    TEST("ab"+*"");
    TEST("abc"+*"");
    TEST(1+"abc");
    TEST(buf);
    TEST(buf + 1);
    TEST(cbuf);
    TEST(cbuf + 1);
    TEST(p);
    TEST(cp);
    TEST(p + 1);
    TEST(cp + 1);
    TEST(&p);
    TEST(&cp);
    TEST(&buf);
    TEST(&cbuf);

    return *cp - *p - 3;
}
```

It only outputs `1` for `TEST(S)`, `TEST("")` and `TEST("abc")`.

Answer (score 3):

Clang's and gcc's `__builtin_constant_p(expr)` returns 1 if expr is a string literal, else it returns 0. Tested with clang 3.5+ and gcc 4.6+.

Since clang pre-defines **GCC**, you can simply

```
#ifdef __GCC__
  ... use __builtin_constant_p(expr)
#else
  ... use fallback
#endif
```

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

Comment: Note, though, that this will only work if optimizations are enabled.  See [**GCC __builtin_constant_p always returning 0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794096/gcc-builtin-constant-p-always-returning-0)

Comment: I think it is now [broken](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80886)

Answer (score 1):

Because a string literal in c++ can have different prefixes then there is no point to check for beginning quote: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Better to check for the ending quote:

- C++11
- msvc2015u3,gcc5.4,clang3.8.0
- https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aandry81%2Ftacklelib+content%3A%22UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING%22&type=code

  ```
    #include <type_traits>

    #define UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE(exp)                   ::utility::const_expr_value<decltype(exp), exp>::value

    // hint: operator* applies to character literals, but not to double-quoted literals
    #define UTILITY_LITERAL_CHAR_(c_str, char_type)         UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE(((void)(c_str * 0), ::utility::literal_char_caster<typename ::utility::remove_cvref<char_type>::type>::cast_from(c_str, L ## c_str, u ## c_str, U ## c_str)))
    #define UTILITY_LITERAL_CHAR(c_str, char_type)          UTILITY_LITERAL_CHAR_(c_str, char_type)

    #define UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING(c_str)                UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE((sizeof(#c_str) > 1) ? #c_str [sizeof(#c_str) - 2] == UTILITY_LITERAL_CHAR('\"', decltype(c_str[0])) : false)

    #define UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_A(c_str)                   UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE((sizeof(#c_str) > 1) ? #c_str [sizeof(#c_str) - 2] == '\"' : false)
    #define UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_WITH_PREFIX(c_str, prefix) UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE((sizeof(#c_str) > 1) ? #c_str [sizeof(#c_str) - 2] == prefix ## '\"' : false)

    namespace utility {

        template <typename T, T v>
        struct const_expr_value
        {
            static constexpr const T value = v;
        };

        // remove_reference + remove_cv
        template <typename T>
        struct remove_cvref
        {
            using type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
        };

        //// literal_char_caster, literal_string_caster

        // template class to replace partial function specialization and avoid overload over different return types
        template <typename CharT>
        struct literal_char_caster;

        template <>
        struct literal_char_caster<char>
        {
            static inline constexpr char
                cast_from(
                    char ach,
                    wchar_t wch,
                    char16_t char16ch,
                    char32_t char32ch)
            {
                return ach;
            }
        };

        template <>
        struct literal_char_caster<wchar_t>
        {
            static inline constexpr wchar_t
                cast_from(
                    char ach,
                    wchar_t wch,
                    char16_t char16ch,
                    char32_t char32ch)
            {
                return wch;
            }
        };

        template <>
        struct literal_char_caster<char16_t>
        {
            static inline constexpr char16_t
                cast_from(
                    char ach,
                    wchar_t wch,
                    char16_t char16ch,
                    char32_t char32ch)
            {
                return char16ch;
            }
        };

        template <>
        struct literal_char_caster<char32_t>
        {
            static inline constexpr char32_t
                cast_from(
                    char ach,
                    wchar_t wch,
                    char16_t char16ch,
                    char32_t char32ch)
            {
                return char32ch;
            }
        };

    }

    const char * a = "123";
    const char b[] = "345";

    int main()
    {
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_A(a) == 0, "Aa");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING(a) == 0, "a");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_A(b) == 0, "Ab");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING(b) == 0, "b");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_A("123") == 1, "A123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_WITH_PREFIX(L"123", L) == 1, "L123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_WITH_PREFIX(u"123", u) == 1, "u123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING_WITH_PREFIX(U"123", U) == 1, "U123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING("123") == 1, "123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING(L"123") == 1, "L123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING(u"123") == 1, "u123");
        static_assert(UTILITY_IS_LITERAL_STRING(U"123") == 1, "U123");
    }
  ```

https://godbolt.org/z/UXIRY6

The `UTILITY_CONST_EXPR_VALUE` macro is required to force a compiler to generate a compile time only code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what the op wants but I use

```
#define literal(a) "" s
#define strcpy(a, b ) _strcpy(a, literal(b))
```

This makes for

```
char buf[32];
char buf2[32];
const char *p = "hello,";

strcpy(buf, "hello"); // legal
strcpy,(buf, p);  // illegal
strcpy(buf, buf2); // illegal
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to enhance the solution of Chris Lutz which he answered in 2011. Using compile time evaluation feature to examine the characters statically.

According to cppref https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal, there are ten string literal syntaxes in total. All of them are supported.

```cpp
#define is_literal(x)             \
    [&]() constexpr {             \
        auto&& str##__line__ = x; \
        return is_literal_f(#x);  \
    }()

constexpr const char* strchr_c(const char* str, char ch) {
    for (; *str != '\0'; str++) {
        if (*str == ch) return str;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

constexpr bool isspace_c(char ch) {
    switch (ch) {
        case ' ':
        case '\f':
        case '\n':
        case '\r':
        case '\t':
        case '\v':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

template <size_t N>
constexpr bool is_literal_f(const char (&str)[N]) {
    constexpr std::array<const char*, 4> tokens[] = {{"R", "L", "u", "U"}, {"u8", "LR", "UR", "uR"}, {"u8R"}};
    constexpr auto tokens_size = std::end(tokens) - std::begin(tokens);

    auto begin = &str[0];
    auto end = &str[N - 1];
    auto it = begin;

    for (auto pos = begin; pos != end; pos++) {
        int diff = pos - begin;
        for (auto token : tokens[diff]) {
            if (token == nullptr) break;
            bool match = true;
            for (int j = 0; j <= diff; j++) {
                if (begin[j] != token[j]) {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
            if (match) {
                it = pos + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (diff == tokens_size - 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (*it != '"') return false;
    for (it = strchr_c(it + 1, '"'); it != end - 1; it = strchr_c(it + 1, '"')) {
        if (it == nullptr) return false;
        it++;
        while (isspace_c(*it)) it++;
        if (*it != '"') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is compatible with c++17, if you use c++20, then it would be better to replace `constexpr` with `consteval`.

The following tests are passed in gcc and apple clang.

```cpp
int main() {
    static_assert(is_literal("abc"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        "a())bc"
        "d"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        "abc"
        "d"
        "ef"
        "g"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        L"abc"
        "def"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        u"abc"
        "def"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        U"abc"
        "def"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        u8"cd"
        "ed"));
    static_assert(is_literal(
        "abc"
        "def"));

    const char str[] = "abc";
    static_assert(!is_literal(str));

    auto&& str2 = "acdefg";
    static_assert(!is_literal(str2));

    static_assert(is_literal(
        u8R"a(
)\
a""
)a"));

    static_assert(is_literal(
        u8R"a(
)\
a""
)a"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
#define is_string_literal(s) \
  (memcmp(#s, "\"", 1) == 0)
```

According to C/C++ variable naming convention, variable name must be start with '_' or an alphabet.

Comment: If you're going to steal my technique and take out all the precautions I've taken to make sure faulty input doesn't ge processed, why bother calling `memcmp` for one character? Just do `(#s[0] == '"')`. Also, macro names won't stringize properly the way you've written it.

Comment: This approach has false positives for expressions that start with a string literal, for example it is true for `"YN"[boolean_value]`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question: I wanted to say that

```
MY_MACRO("compile-time string")
```

was legal, and that

```
char buffer[200]="a string";
MY_MACRO(buffer)
```

was legal, but not to allow

```
MY_MACRO(szArbitraryDynamicString)
```

I used GCC's __builtin_types_compatible_p and MSVC's _countof, which seem to work correctly at the expense of rejecting short string literals.

Answer (score 0):

Could we utilize the [array-size idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408024/how-does-this-template-code-to-get-the-size-of-an-array-work) constrained to `const char` type only here?

To filter out non-literal strings, we pad out the macro parameter with "". This has two desirable outcomes.

1. any non-string type is immediately disqualified
2. any string variable on stack or heap is also disqualified.

```cpp
namespace foo
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    constexpr bool is_string(const char (&str)[N]) { return N > 1U; }
}

#define MACRO(arg) \
    static_assert(foo::is_string(arg ""), "arg must be a non-empty literal string"); \
    {}
```

Requires C++11 and later.

Comment: I think that will return true for any constant char array (or reference thereto), not only something that was written as a string literal.

Comment: It certainly fails a test case of `auto const& r = "hello"; !is_string_literal(r)`.

Comment: Absolutely right, yes. With help from others I have maybe fixed the macro so that it will only accept literal strings. I have tried the failed test case and that seems to get picked out now. See https://godbolt.org/z/94TbabbY6 @TobySpeight

Comment: It's a different compiler error than one would expect, but a compiler error nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

This response may be a bit late, but hopefully it will be helpful to other people asking, my solution was the following:

```
#define _s(x) #x
#define IS_LITERAL(expr) (_s(expr)[0] == '"')
```

The advantage of this solution is that this code can be evaluated at compile time, which will allow for useful optimizations elsewhere.
Also this macro can be compiled with any compiler, no compiler-specific features are used here.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Thanks for your answer. However you may want to explain your answer. As it stands it appears that it will not resolve the question. For example consider `IS_LITERAL("abc"[i] == 'a' ? s : t) `, for integer i and strings s,  t.