# Can the C++ preprocessor tell whether a token is a string?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible for a preprocessor macro to determine whether its argument is a string (literal) or not?

For example:

```
#define IS_STRING(token) ???

IS_STRING("foo")  // expands to 1
IS_STRING(foo)    // expands to 0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this information? There might be a compile-time method in C++(11). I don't think the preprocessor has anything like that.

Comment: I am trying to overload a preprocessor macro based on whether its first argument is a string or not. I just realized, though, that my approach is flawed because there is nothing preventing a user of the macro from declaring a named `const char*` and passing that instead of a string literal, in which case the wrong overload would be called...

Comment: You cannot overload macros. See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3046932/1371116).

Comment: @Isaac: You **can** overload macros, for some senses of "overload". For example, you can declare a variadic macro and then do different things based on the number of arguments it gets (the Boost.Preprocessor library does this).

Comment: How do you have it do something different depending on the number of args?

Comment: @Isaac: Look at e.g. the definition of BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ in http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/preprocessor/tuple/to_seq.hpp

Comment: Those are different macros doing different things, not an overloaded macro...

Comment: @Isaac: That's why I said 'for some senses of "overload"'. The effect is the same as if the macro was overloaded for 1 and 2 arguments.

Comment: It is possible for C++03, based on conversion to `char*`. If it implicitly converts to `char*` and is of type `char const[N]`, it is a string literal. However it is on the compiler level, not on the preprocessor level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. But with a small difference in the output:

```
#define IS_STRING(token) "" token
```

It will go fine for string literal. For non-strings, it will give compiler error.

**Logic**: Compiler concatenates string literal automatically, so `"" token` goes fine, if `token` is a string literal.

[Here is a related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819217/verify-type-of-string-e-g-literal-array-pointer-passed-to-a-function).

Comment: Is there a way that doesn't produce a compiler error for one of the cases?

Comment: @HighCommander4, no it's not possible. Even if whatever function overloads you make. The string literal will either collide with array or character string.