# Check a value at compile time if possible

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'd like to check a value at compile time, if it's a `constexpr` value and do run a `constexpr` form-checking function on it if it is.

Can I do this in c++11/14?

In pseudo code, I'd like to do:

```
static_if (is_constexpr(x)) 
      static_assert(check(x))
```

---

**Details:**

I'm checking a string for a particular format. It's conceptually:

```
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr bool check(const char (&s)[N]){ return true; }
//^ really a recursive call that checks the string
```

The constexpr check works with a string literal, but not with a string pointer:

```
int main(){
  const char* s = "#";
  static_assert(check("#"), "Fmt");; //OK

  //This fails; expectation was it suceeds and the check doesn't run
  static_assert(!is_constexpr(s) || check(s), "Fmt");

}
```

The `is_constexpr` is:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename T> 
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type makeprval(T && t) {
  return t;
}
#define is_constexpr(e) noexcept(makeprval(e))
```

Comment: The "duplicate" refers to producing a `bool` that holds this result.  If you want to abort compilation instead, then perhaps different solutions are possible.

Comment: How about `static_assert(x || !x, "");` . If `x` is not constant this will fail to compile, and if it is constant then nothing happens.

Comment: @M.M I only want to abort compilation if the value is constexpr and my constexpr check failed.

Comment: OK, I have reopened the question as this is substantially different to the previous duplicate

Comment: The stuff in your "details" is different to your original question. `"#"` is a constant expression, but `s` is not a constant expression.

Comment: I don't understand what the line `//static_assert(/*!is_constexpr(s) ||*/ check(s), "Fmt");; //doesn't work` is supposed to be saying, could you try to write this a bit more clearly  (show the actual code that "doesn't work" and explain how the behaviour differs from what you expected)

Comment: `static_assert(!is_constexpr(s) || check(s), "Fmt");` this should work -- it either shouldn't be constexpr or the constexpr check should run. I concede that the linked question is a duplicate. (Unfortunately, the proposed solution doesn't work, but that's another issue). You can close this one.

Comment: Well, it's not a duplicate IMO, but if you're happy that your problem is solved by the other thread then we can leave this

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect your last comment , and removed the stuff about the other solution not compiling. (Post a comment on the actual answer containing that code, if it doesn't work)

Comment: @PSkocik: I understand what you're trying to do, although I don't know how to do it, or if it is even possible.  I think your problem is considerably more complex than the linked question, since even once `is_constexpr()` is made to work, you may still have a problem that an unevaluated part of `!is_constexpr(s) || check(s)` isn't a constant expression.  Based on my understanding, you're looking to implement `static_if (is_constexpr(s)) static_assert(check(s))`

Comment: M.M seems to have missed the point repeatedly, so I've tried to undo his well-intentioned but damaging changes.  If he keeps making changes you don't agree with, try starting a post on meta or raise a moderator flag.

Comment: @BenVoigt if I am missing the point, it suggests that the question could be edited to more clearly express what the point is ... perhaps you could do that

Comment: Well there's [this hack](http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2015/07/simulate-static_if-with-c11c14.html), that, when combined with [this other hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13305072/27678), could be used to produce something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa6ef098394973a4). Would that solve your issue?

Comment: Well, right now your sample code does not compile because `check(s)` doesn't compile at all (there's no viable overload of `check` for `const char *`). The simplest fix for that is probably adding a `bool check(...);` overload. Is that your actual issue, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

May be your question is bit unclearer to me. If you want whether a string literal should pass and pointer should not then look at below answer. Should you feel that, I have misunderstood your question then comment it, I shall delete this answer or modify accordingly.

You can use simple C-style macro to check if given variable is a string literal, as I have explained in my answer to below question:
[Verify type of string (e.g. literal, array, pointer) passed to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5819217/514235)

```
#define IS_LITERAL(X) "" X
```

The compilation will fail if the `X` is not a string literal.