# Compile-time strings: constructor overload precedence between `const char *` / `const char[]`

Tags: c++, string, constexpr, compile-time-constant, constructor-overloading

I am trying to make a compile-time string class. I took a few hints from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c). Unfortunately, I'm stuck on constructor overload precedence: the `const char[]` constructor is being ignored in favor of the  `const char*` constructor.  Any tips would be appreciated!

```
class string {
 public:
  // Can be done compile time. Works lovely! except...
  template<size_t N>
  constexpr string(const char(&char_array)[N])
      : ptr_(char_array), length_(N-1) {}

  // This override gets called instead.  I *must* keep this constructor.
  string(const char* const str)
      : ptr_(str) {
    length_ = strlen(str);
  }

  // Ugly hack. (not acceptable)
  template<size_t N>
  constexpr string(const char(&char_array)[N], double unused)
      : ptr_(char_array), length_(N-1) {}

 private:
  const char* ptr_;
  int length_;
};




constexpr const char kConstant[] = "FooBarBaz";

constexpr string kString(kConstant); // Error: constexpr variable 'kString' must be initialized by a constant expression (tries to call wrong overload)

constexpr string kString(kConstant, 1.0f); // ugly hack works.
```

There's lots of cool things I can do if I can make compile-time string constants.

- string equality testing is faster on `string` than `const char *`
- Eliminate run-time overhead of implicit conversions from `const char *` to `string` that call `strlen()` on compile-time constant strings.
- Compile-time string sets that do equality testing instead of hashing for size < N. (this is multiple cpus of overhead on one application I'm looking at)

Comment: If you look at [the `std::string` constructor overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you will see that they don't even bother with arrays, only pointers.

Comment: They also don't support constexpr construction! That's the point. The templatized character array is capable of detecting string size at compile-time.

Comment: non-templated function has a preference over templated, even when it requires pointer decay. I do not know how to fix this, though. I had the same problem myself when I tried that, and finally settled on strings based on variadic templates.

Comment: this code does not compile in gcc 5.1.0 even if I comment out `string(const char *)` is it problem with compiler? -  error: ‘string{((const char*)(& kConstant)), 9}’ is not a constant expression

Comment: @Slava, compiles for me...

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28437613/2069064 ?

Comment: Though not `constexpr`, `strlen(str)` implemented using `__builtin_strlen` *will* be able to determine the length of a string literal at compile time. Is that not good enough?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit ugly, but it should work:

```
template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, char>>>
string(const T * const & str)
    : ptr_(str) {
  length_ = strlen(str);
}
```

The trick is that taking the pointer by const reference blocks array-to-pointer decay during template argument deduction, so when you pass an array, the compiler can't deduce `T` and the constructor is ignored.

The drawback is that this would also reject other things that are implicitly convertible to `const char *`.

---

An alternative might be to accept everything convertible to `const char *`, and then dispatch based on whether said thing is an array.

```
template<size_t N>
constexpr string(const char(&char_array)[N], std::true_type)
    : ptr_(char_array), length_(N-1) {}

string(const char * str, std::false_type)
    : ptr_(str) {
  length_ = strlen(str);
}

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, const char *>>>
constexpr string(T&& t) 
    : string(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_array<std::remove_reference_t<T>>()) {}
```

Comment: Impressive.  I tried something similar but couldn't get it working without the pointer decay trick.  +1 for explaining why the `const &` makes a difference.  Unfortunately, I don't think I'll be able to get that past code-review as it complicated the vanilla code-path.