# GCC __builtin_constant_p always returning 0

Tags: c, gcc

I have the following code:

```
const int a = 10;
int b = __builtin_constant_p(a);
printf("%d\n", b);
```

output is 0.
I read the man, the value of 0 doesn't mean that a *is not a compile time constant*, just that gcc can't prove that it is. Anyway I can get this output to be 1?

Comment: A 'constant expression', according to the C standard is different from a 'constant value'. `__builtin_constant_p` checks for a constant expression.

There's simply no way to do what you want here, without turning `a` into a macro. A variable will never be a 'constant expression'.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: [As documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), `__builtin_constant_p` does not determine if the operand is a constant expression but "if a value is known to be constant at compile time and hence that GCC can perform constant-folding on expressions involving that value". OP is probably omitting `-O`...

Answer (score 3):

A `const`-qualified variable is **not** a constant expression in C, but GCC does not document `__builtin_constant_p` as determining if the argument is a constant expression anyway. Rather, it's [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to "determine if a value is known to be constant at compile time and hence that GCC can perform constant-folding on expressions involving that value". So it should be usable for what you want.

The problem is almost certainly just that you compiled with `-O0` (no optimization, the default), in which case no constant-folding can take place because you have it turned off. Turn on optimization (at least `-O1`, but normally you want `-O2` or `-Os`) and it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

A variable is never a constant (unless constant folding is used, but you have to have optimization enabled for that), even if it is `const`-qualified.

`__builtin_constant_p` will return true for a constant only. For example:

```
int b = __builtin_constant_p(10);
printf("%d\n", b);
```

will print `1`.

Note that your code will print `1` also if you compile with optimization enabled (`-O` at minimum, but any other legal `-O` flag will work except for `-O0`).