# Implementation of is_a_compile_time_c_string?

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, clang++

I would like to detect whether an argument is a compile time c string:

```
template <class T>
consteval bool is_a_compile_time_c_string(T&& t) {
   // magic
}
```

Some suggested builtin_constant_p() but it seems like it is [broken](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80886).

I wonder given C++20, is it possible?  I am okay with macro/template/compiler built-in as long as it can determine whether the argument is a c string at compile time.

Thanks!

More concrete examples to express my need:

```
template <class U>
bool verify(U&& t) {
    return is_a_compile_time_c_string(t);
}


int main() {
    std::cout << is_a_compile_time_c_string("test_1") << std::endl;
    const char* s1 = "test_1";
    std::cout << is_a_compile_time_c_string(s1) << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << verify(s1) << std::endl; // 1
    char s2[5];
    s2[0] = 'a';
    s2[1] = 0;
    std::cout << is_a_compile_time_c_string(s2) << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << verify(s2) << std::endl; // 0
}
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691232/can-i-determine-if-an-argument-is-string-literal

Comment: "_is a compile time c string_": What _exactly_ do you mean? That the argument is a string literal? That it is a `(const) char*` or `(const) char[N]` null-terminated string that is a constant subexpression?

Comment: @user17732522 yeah, basically those strings that reside in read-only section in the binary, which never get destroyed.

Comment: @康桓瑋 thanks.  good reference.  just no straightforward answer there.

Comment: @HCSF I still don't know what exactly you want. For example with `const char s[] = "1234";`, `s` is also likely stored in read-only memory, but `s` is not a string literal and `s` is not usable in constant expressions. What is the purpose of this determination? The issue you linked also indicates that you are not interested in whether something is compile-time usable in the sense of the C++ language, because it is specifically about `(void *) 0x1000`, which can't be compile-time usable in C++, regardless of whether the address `0x1000` is located in read-only memory.

Comment: @user17732522 added examples to express my need.

Comment: So is it supposed to be dependent on what optimizations the compiler makes? Because if it e.g. doesn't inline `verify`, then it can't see that `t`/`s1` is guaranteed to point to a string literal. What if it is non-obvious that `s1` points to a string literal? It could be an arbitrary complex function initializing it. `s1` itself is not usable in constant expressions at the language level (it would need to be `constexpr` for that).

Comment: @user17732522 so yes, you are right that I am "not interested in whether something is compile-time usable in the sense of the C++ language".  But it doesn't hurt if it is "compile-time usable".  Could you elaborate about `(void*) 0x1000`?

Comment: @HCSF Not compile-time usable means that `constexpr auto x = foo((void*) 0x1000);` will never compile, regardless of what `foo` does, because `(void*)` here resolves to a `reinterpret_cast` that is never allowed in a constant expression. That is however completely unrelated to whether or not the compiler knows that `(void*) 0x1000` is a constant value that can e.g. be constant-folded. If you are interested in that, then you need `__builtin_constant_p`, but it doesn't tell you anything about whether you can use it with `constexpr`. In the linked issue the two are somehow conflated.

Comment: Also, `__builtin_constant_p` is optimization-dependent, since it is not operating on the language level, but on what the compiler actually knows.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for your explanation.  I think to simplify -- I am looking for a way to determine whether a memory location (at runtime) resides in read-only section.  This way, I can safely pass the memory location (pointer) around threads without deep copy.  Hope this answers your doubt why I am trying to get this function.

Comment: @HCSF From what you told me until now I think the best bet is `__builtin_constant_p`, but I don't feel that this is a good approach in general. Whether or not you can know that a `const char*` points to a static storage-duration string depends on how much analysis the compiler does. So the behavior may vary with flags and compiler versions. It would be safer to manage the object lifetimes properly in the scope of the language instead.

Comment: yes, I tested with `__builtin_constant_p` and clang 10.  It fails in some cases.  That's why I came here and hope for an absolute way to solve this.

Comment: @HCSF It can't be solved absolutely. The caller of `verify` may have done any complex calculation to produce the value of `t`. Deciding whether or not `t` is guaranteed to point to a string literal at any given call site of `verify` is an undecidable problem (if there is dependence on input). You must accept false-negatives like `__builtin_constant_p` has and that the quality will depend on the optimizer resources spent.

Comment: @user17732522 Is possible to do something like this `if ((void*)ptr < END_OF_RDONLY_ADDR) { /* in readonly section */ } else { /* no */ }`?  I am not sure whether it is possible to get END_OF_RDONLO_ADDR programmatically during compile time or at runtime...certainly it is possible by using ELF parser and then passing in as a command argument,  but it is ugly.

Comment: @HCSF That won't help determining it _at compile-time_ though. But if you want to go that runtime route, I suppose you can probably write a linker script that gives you the beginning and end of the `.rodata` section as symbols to compare to or something like that. The details may depend on what target you are compiling for. I don't know much about that area though.

Comment: yes, the solution I proposed is a runtime solution as it seems like compile-time solution doesn't exist.  thanks for sharing thoughts all the way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that.

This is also the reason why [`format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) and [`formatv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/vformat) are functions with different names instead of just two overloads with identical names.

What you can do is check if your function is executed in a `constexpr` context. This does not refer to the arguments it is called with, but to the environment it is called in!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> // C++20 only for std::is_constant_evaluated

constexpr bool called_as_constexpr() {
    // C++23; simple use
    // if consteval {
    // or C++20: not "if constexpr"! thats always true!
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here are examples what a `constexpr` context is and what not:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    auto no = called_as_constexpr();
    std::cout << "no: " << no << '\n';

    constexpr auto yes = called_as_constexpr(); // constexpr context
    std::cout << "yes: " << yes << '\n';

    std::cout << "inline: " << called_as_constexpr() << '\n';

    static_assert(called_as_constexpr(), "This is a constexpr context!");

    if (called_as_constexpr()) {
        std::cout << "normal if condition: true\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "normal if condition: false\n";
    }

    if constexpr (called_as_constexpr()) {
        std::cout << "constexpr if condition: true\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "constexpr if condition: false\n";
    }
}
```

```
no: false
yes: true
inline: false
normal if condition: false
constexpr if condition: true
```